# Calling a function inside an AJAX success response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm basically trying to call a function which is outside of my AJAX inside the AJAX success response.

To explain this better, this is what I have.

These are two functions:

```
function watchCurrentPosition() {
    var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
        setMarkerPosition(userLocation, position);
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)); 

    });

}

function clearmyWatch() { 

   navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(positionTimer);
}
```

One of them keeps watching the users location and the other one 'should' stop it.

And this is how I'm calling the `clearmyWatch();` function inside the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"TEST.PHP",
      datatype:"html",
      success:function(data)
      {
clearmyWatch();
      }
    });
```

However, this doesn't work and the `watchCurrentPosition();` constantly running and I also get an error in my console.

The error that I am getting is this:

```
ReferenceError: positionTimer is not defined
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define `positionTimer ` in global scope

Comment: positionTimer is a local variable try declaring it globally

Comment: Or better yet put this all into a closure so you don't polute the global scope

Comment: You got your answer, however I suggest you to read about scopes in js. read also about scopes in lambda functions.  You need to master it now because compilers doesn't complain about it and leaves you with tricky bugs and unexpected behavior.

Comment: Why didn't you accept my answer, not only I was first, but the solution is much better and more elegant.It avoids a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `positionTimer` at global level outside of `function watchCurrentPosition()` like:

```
var positionTimer = null;

function watchCurrentPosition() {
     positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
        setMarkerPosition(userLocation, position);
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)); 

    });

}

function clearmyWatch() { 
    if(positionTimer)
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(positionTimer);
}
```

Comment: In general global level variables should be avoided. I this case it can be solved elegantly without a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

`positionTimer` is local to `watchCurrentPosition`

**The better way to solve it without global variables is:**

```
function watchCurrentPosition() {
    var  positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
        setMarkerPosition(userLocation, position);
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)); 

    });

    clearmyWatch=()=>{
     navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(positionTimer);
    }

}

function clearmyWatch() {}
```

Explanation: `clearmyWatch` is defined in a way that it does nothing.However calling `watchCurrentPosition` sets `clearmyWatch` as an inner function of `watchCurrentPosition` that can get to `positionTimer`. Actually by setting `clearmyWatch` to an inner function of `watchCurrentPosition` we create a closure (read about it of you don't know what it is, it's important).